# Update Column in Table A based off of matching values of multiple rows in Table B

Tags: sql, oracle

Before I ask my question, let me give some background to my tables.  I have a table titled "**Tickets**" and another table titled "**Disciplines**".  "**Tickets**" keeps track of all the Work Request Tickets.  In these work requests, you can have 1 or more "Type of Work Requested" to full-fill the ticket request.  These individual requests are stored in the **Disciplines** table.  Once a user completes their work, that discipline's "Status" is updated to "Complete" (disciplines.status_id = 3).  Once all disciplines.status_id is updated to "3", I need to update the ticket.status_id=3 automatically.  How can this be done?

**Ticket Table :**

[image: Ticket Table]

**Discipline Table :**

[image: Discipline Table]

- status_id = 1 (open)
- status_id = 2 (working)
- status_id = 3 (closed)

Was thinking I needed to write an IF - THEN statement and compare the SUM of the values.  If they equal, they trigger the UPDATE statement?  Something like:

```
select COUNT(WD.status_id) * 3 
from disciplines WD
where  WD.ticket_id = [ticket id]
```

Do a comparison with...

```
select SUM(WD.status_id) 
from disciplines WD
where  WD.ticket_id = [ticket id]
```

I'm so lost... help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to contain the information from the pictures in textual form. Edit it to make use of formatting options for the sake fo readabilty. Add a [mcve] by providing suitable lines of `create table...` and `ìnsert into...` to recreate a toy version of your database.

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem - you have provided 2 queries - you could've select their values into variables and compare them with `if/ else` as you intended to  ... if you are trying to do that inside a `trigger` you could hit mutating trigger issue though ... Please  clarify  what is the problem exactly...

Comment: Plirkee - Sorry, still new to writing queries.  I guess I needed a sounding board.  Also, not exactly that fluent with complex queries.  I'll take a stab at storing them into variables (which i'm not 100% sure how to do) then do the If/Else Comparison.  What do you mean by mutating trigger?

Comment: So I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct logic.  Basically what I want is, if all the rows in the discipline table have a status_id=3, then I want to update the ticket.status_id = 3, but not until all rows in discipline have been updated to 3.  Hope that makes more sense?